# Make multiple but separate characters in string bold

Tags: excel, format, vba

I have a cell that has text, like this:

k a2 d eu1 n   -   oe2 r gj y2 t lj e2 r i1   -   t y1 r kj   -   jh e2 z aa1

Eventually it should be like this:

k a2 d **eu**1 n   -   oe2 r gj y2 t lj e2 r **i**1   -   t **y**1 r kj   -   jh e2 z **aa**1

For the purposes of this the value of the cell is stored in variable v3.

```
Public Sub Guide()


Dim v3 As String
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim pos, pos1 As Long

v3 = Sheets("Script").Cells(12, 8).Value

i = 1
j = 0

Do
   j = InStr(i, v3, "1", vbTextCompare)
   i = j + 1


   pos = InStrRev(v3, " ", (j - 1))
   pos1 = (j - 1) - pos

 Call BoldText(v3, j - pos1, pos1)

Loop Until j = 0


End Sub
```

This is how I get the position of the letter before 1, `(j - 1)`, and how many characters between the previous space and 1, `pos1`...

This is "BoldText":

```
Sub BoldText(Txt, strt As Integer, Lngt)
Dim Ln As Long

Ln = Len(Txt)



Range("H12").Select

With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=(strt - 1)).Font
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
End With
With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=strt, Length:=Lngt).Font
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
End With
With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=(strt + Lngt + 1), Length:=(Ln - strt)).Font
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
End With


End Sub
```

So this way it keeps characters `1 to (one before the bold)`  regular font. The ones we want go bold, then `(one after bold) to End` regular again.

How would it be possible to achieve this with multiple instances so that the end result is achieved?

At the moment, on each loop it resets the last.  Excel expects it to be in the syntax of `1 to (x - 1)` = regular font, `x` = bold font, `x + 1 to (y-1)` = regular, `y` = bold, `y + 1 to (z - 1)` etc...  I'm just not sure how to script that.

Many thanks in advance. 
If you need anything clearer then I can do my best to explain some more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit rushed (and a bit of a hack), but should start you off at least. It uses regular expressions. You could turn some of it into a sub with parameters.

```
Sub Regex2()

Dim oMatches As Object, i As Long, vOut

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\s([a-z]+)1"
    Set oMatches = .Execute(Range("A1"))
End With

ReDim vOut(0 To oMatches.Count - 1, 1 To 3)

For i = 0 To oMatches.Count - 1
    vOut(i, 1) = oMatches(i).submatches(0)
    vOut(i, 2) = oMatches(i).firstindex
    vOut(i, 3) = oMatches(i).Length
Next i

For i = LBound(vOut) To UBound(vOut)
    Range("A1").Characters(vOut(i, 2) + 1, vOut(i, 3) - 1).Font.Bold = True
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Incredible, thank you for the speedy reply! It does the job perfectly, I shall just adapt it for my exact needs.

Comment: Glad it works. I will come back later and tidy it up a bit.

Comment: Something that has come up since implementing that. How would I go about then removing the '1's and '2's without resetting the formatting?  the Replace function sadly overwrites the bold

Comment: If you remove the numbers, is there any way to distinguish the bits of text you are interested in from the rest? If not, you can search for each string, which is stored in vOut, and its location and then use Characters again. I don't have time now, but if you get stuck I can re-work the code later.

Comment: Another complication is if you have duplicates, e.g. there is more than 1 y in your string.